# Using docker cloud from jenkins running on local osx docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-in-docker, macos

Hopefully someone can help, I've found lots of information online but as I'm brand new to both jenkins and docker, I'm having a hard time sorting out which suggested solutions happen on the what machine, so I'm cargo culting without any success.

Setup I'm attempting:
- physical box is OSX with docker for mac installed
- I created a docker container that runs jenkins, it works, I can make a hello-world job run fine on the master node
- I want to create dynamic docker build agents
- I've tried configuring the Docker Cloud plugin to make build agents from the evarga/jenkins-slave image
- I don't know what to put in Docker Host URI. I have tried tcp://127.0.0.1:2376 but when I "Test Connection" I get a Connection Refused error message.
- I've also tried /var/run/docker.sock as the HOST URI and in that case I get a 403 "No valid crumb was included in the request"

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Is port 2376 open on your container?

Comment: Good point. I was following a book, and maybe they've made a mistake. Both the jenkins docker container and the slave containers I'm trying to start are running on the docker VM managed by Docker for Mac. Do you know if I need to do anything special to let them connect to each other? I'll start digging.

Comment: Could you post an answer?